# javascript if else not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following html:

```
<select name="user_level" id="user_level" class="input" onChange="javascript:choosePackage(this.value);" >
<option value="1" >Single</option>
<option value="3" >Multi</option>   
<option value="7" >Super</option>                     
</select>

<div id="showPackageSelect" ></div>
```

And this is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function choosePackage(packageselected){

if(packageselected=='3') { $("#showPackageSelect").replaceWith("<div id='normal'>User Package</div><select name='user_package' id='user_package' class='input'><?php $rPackages = mysql_query('select * from packages WHERE id>=2 AND id <=5 ORDER BY id DESC');while ($rp = mysql_fetch_array($rPackages)) { ?><option value='<?php echo $rp['id'];?>'><?php echo $rp['package'];?></option><?php } ?></select>");

} else if(packageselected=='1') { $("#showPackageSelect").replaceWith("<div id='normal'>User Package</div><select name='user_package' id='user_package' class='input'><option value='1'>Super User</option></select>");

} else if(packageselected=='6') { $("#showPackageSelect").replaceWith("<div id='normal'>User Package</div><select name='user_package' id='user_package' class='input'><option value='6'>Single</option></select>"); 

} else { alert('this should never happen!'); }

}

</script>
```

I have tried several ways using if else etc..
The funny thing is that when i alert the value it works fine, and when i test it it does it once but then after that wont change back to single.

Thanks in advance
Jonny

UPDATE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function choosePackage(packageselected){

if(packageselected=='3')
$("#showPackageSelect").replaceWith("<div id='showPackageSelect' ><div id='normal'>User Package</div><select name='user_package' id='user_package' class='input'><?php $rPackages = mysql_query('select * from packages WHERE id>=2 AND id <=5 ORDER BY id DESC');while ($rp = mysql_fetch_array($rPackages)) { ?><option value='<?php echo $rp['id'];?>'><?php echo $rp['package'];?></option><?php } ?></select></div>");

else if(packageselected=='1') 
$("#showPackageSelect").replaceWith("<div id='showPackageSelect' ><div id='normal'>User Package</div><select name='user_package' id='user_package' class='input'><option value='1'>Super User</option></select></div>");

else if(packageselected=='7')
$("#showPackageSelect").replaceWith("<div id='showPackageSelect' ><div id='normal'>User Package</div><select name='user_package' id='user_package' class='input'><option value='6'>Single</option></select></div>"); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if(packageselected=='6')` be `if(packageselected=='7')`?

Comment: have you tried using alert() to really see what the value of packageselected really is?

Comment: You are testing for 6 in the script, but 7 is the value in the drop down..?

Comment: Aside from what @DennisMeng pointed out I can't reproduce your problem. It works for me in a fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/7hcCw/

Comment: Have you considered AJAX? At least will make it readable

Comment: Hi, yes youre right. BUt i found my problem. The issue was not a wrong value. The question was that it only does it once. Thats because i did not add the actual div inside the replaceWith(). I have updated my code.

Comment: thanks guys for your comments, its fixed now and the best answer was really from @Zhihaho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) says:

> The .replaceWith() method removes content from the DOM and inserts new
>   content in its place with a single call.

I believe you are replacing `showPackageSelect` with the content you put in the `.replaceWith()` function. In other words, you are removing `showPackageSelect` on the first `onChange` event from the DOM. Since the `div` no longer exists in the DOM, the `choosePackage()` function no longer works because it cannot find the `showPackageSelect` `div` anymore. This may be why it only works the first time.

If you want to change the contents using your current method, I would recommend you use `.html()` which changes the HTML in the `div`. Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/efmQv/1/) of your code using `.html()`.

Comment: totally true. I have updated my question with working code. I know there's probably 20 ways to do this better but it works on all browsers and im happy with that.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a "select" element's value, you cannot simply get its value through    .value, but instead you would need to traverse through all of its options and find out which one(s) are selected.  This is because "select" element can allow multiple selection.

Given you are already using jQuery for your script, perhaps it would be easier with the following script:

```
$("#user_level").change(function(eventObject){
    var packageSelected = $("option:selected", eventObject).val();

    if(packageselected=='3') {
        $("#showPackageSelect").replaceWith("<div id='normal'>User Package</div><select name='user_package' id='user_package' class='input'><?php $rPackages = mysql_query('select * from packages WHERE id>=2 AND id <=5 ORDER BY id DESC');while ($rp = mysql_fetch_array($rPackages)) { ?><option value='<?php echo $rp['id'];?>'><?php echo $rp['package'];?></option><?php } ?></select>");
    } else if (packageselected=='1') {
        $("#showPackageSelect").replaceWith("<div id='normal'>User Package</div><select name='user_package' id='user_package' class='input'><option value='1'>Super User</option></select>");
    } else if (packageselected=='6') {
        $("#showPackageSelect").replaceWith("<div id='normal'>User Package</div><select name='user_package' id='user_package' class='input'><option value='6'>Single</option></select>");
    } else {
        alert('this should never happen!');
    }

});
```